# Find array key where value contains a specific value

Tags: php

I have an associative array where each value is a list of numbers, like this:

```
$a['i']=[111, 333];
```

Given the value `333`, how can I find the key `i`. That is, the key for a list which contains `333`.

Comment: You are talking about associative arrays ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values in your primary array were simple types - numbers, strings, etc. - you would want to use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the associated key. In your case the value of each element is another array, so you have to explicitly loop over each element and search the resulting array for your value. Something like this should do the trick:

```
function get_key_from_value(array $arr, $needle)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
        if (in_array($needle, $value, true))
            return $key;
    return null;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
echo get_key_from_value($a, 333);
```

**Update:** It has been mentioned in comments that this is not a general purpose solution, so I've implemented a version that is:

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, array $haystack, $strict = false)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!is_null(array_search_recursive($needle, $value, $strict))) {
                return $key;
            }
        } else {
            if ($strict && $value === $needle) {
                return $key;
            } else if (!$strict && $value == $needle) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which can be called like this (the order of arguments is based on [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)):

```
echo array_search_recursive(333, $a);
```